# How to convert MDB to DXF with labels using ogr2ogr?

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, dxf, personal-geodatabase, batch

I have to convert some 700 MDB files (parcel layer). I want to generate DXF from from them. I tried

`ogr2ogr -f "DXF" d:\01Chitapol_1Ka.dxf d:\01Chitapol_1Ka.mdb`

This gives me the lines. I want the parcel numbers as labels in the DXF file. [This post](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/dxf.html#dxf-writer) mentions using HEADER and LABEL. I couldn't find examples of using this.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/835 has an example. It shows how the label syntax works. It creates a separate label file in DXF format.